# Unbind project from source control in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

By mistake I added my project to GIT repository. Now I would like to change the repository to TFS.

On many websites its mentioned first to select the solution, then go to File menu> Source Control> Change Source Control.

However, I am unable to see this option. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You did nothing wrong. `Source Control` option is not available for Git repository.

Close VS, go to the solution folder of your GIT repository, and remove the hidden `.git` folder, as well as the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` files.